# automated post-deployment testing of symphony chatbot

Tags: java, chatbot

Say I have a [symphony](https://symphony.com/) chatbot in deployed in a development environment and would like to run tests against it like I would manually (through the symphony dev pod client) but in an automated fashion.
A test should start by putting a message on the datafeed of the MIM stream in a dedicated symphony test room (which is locked to only contain the bot, bot tester and human tester) - ideally by going through the symphony gui - and compare the messageML response from the bot to an expected answer. The test should fail if the bot is not reachable (there is no answer within x seconds) or if the response is not what is expected.
To be a bit more precise, I am not looking to test my backend rest apis (which I already do with rest assured) but I want to test the bot end-to-end after deployment in a manner as close as possible to a manual tester.

What I am looking for is an inspiration for what technology to use here. Would frameworks like selenium/botium work?

I hope this question is not too broad but it's more a highlevel development question. I should also mention that I would prefer an implementation in java.

Thanks for the help